# automating Login

Tags: vb.net

There are quite a few forms on automating login but i cannot seem to find one that works for me. I'm using MVS 2010 and if there was any double this is a console application trying to access web browsers.  Here are my two relevant subs.

```
' Navigates to the given URL if it is valid. 
Private Sub Navigate(ByVal address As String)
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(address) Then Return

    If address.Equals("about:blank") Then Return

    If Not address.StartsWith("http://") And Not address.StartsWith("https://") Then
        address = "http://" & address
    End If

    Try
        webBrowser1.Navigate(New Uri(address))
    Catch ex As System.UriFormatException
        Return
    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted() Handles webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

    While webBrowser1.IsBusy
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30)
    End While

    If Not webBrowser1.IsBusy Then
        For Each ele As HtmlElement In webBrowser1.Document.All
            If ele.GetAttribute("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LoginButton").ToLower = "Login" Then
                ele.InvokeMember("click")
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

As you may see it never hits the documentcomplete but it never launched a new web browser. If i change the code to the following a new web browser will open but it will not click the button.

```
   webBrowser1.Navigate(New Uri(address), true)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you for saving me the heart ache later when my question gets answered! However, that still doesn't get me anywhere.

Comment: Please don't insert tags in titles - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: How are you hosting your WebBrowser control what is its parent?

Comment: Im hoping to just use inernet explorer and not have to host it